# Store NSMeasurement or NSUnit in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, ios10

iOS 10 introduces new classes for measurements and units. I would like to either store a NSMeasurement or NSUnit object in my core data database, so that I can store different measurements in my database.

Is there a good way to do this? Since my app would only use a subset of all available units, I could in theory create a string representation of the units and use a switch statement to get the actual unit classes from that when needed. But that feels overly complicated and error prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of those classes conform to `NSCoding`, so you can a store them as "transformable" attributes. As transformables, you read/write object values directly from/to the attribute, and Core Data automatically converts between the object type and `NSData` as needed. You don't need to do any conversions of your own.

Comment: Well that was easier than expected. I accidentally set it to "binary data" instead of "transformable". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Archiving an `NSUnit` will add a lot of storage and performance overhead. Therefore it might be preferrable to store the values as scalar types of the appropriate `NSUnit`'s `baseUnit` and use an `NSMeasurementFormatter` to display values in the UI.