# Changing the weight system used in app based on user selected metrics?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to offer the user the choice of imperial or metric measurement of weight in my app to increase audience suitability. I have designed the following below to allow me to determine which setting the user wishes to use.

However, im unsure how I would go about applying the metric selection to the whole rest of the app? Would it be a case of setting the app reach into each object the user has created in coredata and all text labels relating to a weight measurement and alter their weight property by multiplication or division each time the user changes weight system?

Appreciate any insight into how I may achieve this as I didnt want to go too far in the wrong direction!

```
func convertAppMetric() {
    if self.userSelectedWeightSystem == "Metric" {
        print("THE USER SET THE APP TO METRIC, CONVERTING FIGURES...")
        //some code
    } else if self.userSelectedWeightSystem == "Imperial" {
        print("THE USER SET THE APP TO IMPERIAL, CONVERTING FIGURES...")
        //some other code
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just store one value inside your core-data model, and handle the metric / imperial conversion with a simple computed property.

Comment: Can you expand on this sorry? Im new to swift and ios! At the moment the user stores whatever weight they input so for example a generic "60", so assuming that was metric i would need to run a x2.2 on it if the app went imperial

Comment: Well the good news is that if you're targeting iOS8+ there are already system provided formatters for all kinds of stuff such as ByteCount, Energy, Length, Mass etc that will handle the conversion & proper unit display automatically based on a given locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be one of those answers that SO hates, but you want to go read up on [NSMeasurement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmeasurement).

NSMeasurement holds both a value and a Unit, the later of which is the original measurement type. You store all your data in the format that was originally provided - if the user puts in pounds, store a NSMeasurement with 182 pounds. If they put in kg, make one with 90 kg. You can even put in your own Units, like stone.

From then on, always present the data using an NSMeasurementFormatter. You can pass in the output type, which in your case is the global setting you mentioned in your question. This means that no matter what unit they provided, it always comes out properly converted to the one you want, and changing it instantly changes it everywhere.

Its easy to make your own converters for weird units. I made one for decimal inches and feet/inches, so 13.5 inches turns into 1' 1.5".

Comment: This sounds like the best solution, i will have to research integration of the method into my existing core data code!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423243/store-nsmeasurement-or-nsunit-in-core-data#38423770

Comment: Do you know of any possible cause for it to display metrics fine when set as USA but when i set it to UK to get KG, it isnt loading the data into the textfields, despite it being printed in the console and running the same code as the USA config

Comment: So just to be sure, when you set it to US do you get pounds? Perhaps paste a little output from both cases in the question. This COULD be just a screen update issue, but I doubt it.